Couldn't manage to setup a firewall in Debian 12 using nft, but with ufw worked as intended
I'm studying Kubernetes and how to setup a Kubernetes cluster. For this I'm using KVM, on my virtual machines setup I have defined a bridge connection to connect the VM directly into my router, so I can ssh from another computer.
I choose to use Debian 12, and I don't know if this changes anything, but on the installation process I choose the option to install ssh server, so I don't need to install myself when it boots.
After the installation I do the recommended steps on the Kubernetes page, to check if port 6443 is open and to disable swap(I'm not using swap on those VMs). I do the installation of Kubernetes and the required components(containerd, gpc, etc).
After that I tried to use nft to open the required ports (6443, 2379,2380, 10250,10251,10252, 10255). I used the following command to open those ports with nft:
nft add rule ip filter INPUT tcp dport x accept

And I did that to all ports, for INPUT and OUTPUT. When I'm starting my cluster, it keeps trying to start the scheduler, controller-manager, proxy. But the controller and proxy keeps getting CrashLoopBackOff and when I check the logs it says something like that:
connection refused, 192.168.0.x:6443 

I knew that this was a firewall problem because of the nature of the logs, but what I didn't get is why this is happening if I had opened all the required ports. To try to check if I was correct, I created a new VM with a fresh Debian 12 installation and instead of using nft to setup the firewall, I installed ufw and used the following command to open the required ports:
ufw allow x

And this worked, the cluster was up and running without any errors. Now my question is, why does ufw allow works while nft does not, even if both of then are supposed to open the ports? From the Debian 12 official documentation they say to use nft and do not recommend to install other tools to deal with firewall.
Let me get a piece of /etc/nftables.conf file from the VM that is not working(nft one):
table ip filter {
chain INPUT {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    ct state new  counter jump KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL
     counter jump KUBE-NODEPORTS
    ct state new  counter jump KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
    counter jump KUBE-FIREWALL
    tcp dport 22 accept
    tcp dport 80 accept
    tcp dport 8080 accept
    tcp dport 6443 accept
    tcp dport 443 accept
    tcp dport 2379 accept
    tcp dport 2380 accept
    tcp dport 10250 accept
    tcp dport 10251 accept
    tcp dport 10252 accept
    tcp dport 10255 accept
}

chain OUTPUT {
    type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    ct state new  counter jump KUBE-PROXY-FIREWALL
    ct state new  counter jump KUBE-SERVICES
    counter jump KUBE-FIREWALL
    tcp dport 443 accept
    tcp dport 6443 accept
    tcp dport 80 accept
    tcp dport 8080 accept
    tcp dport 22 accept
    tcp dport 10255 accept
    tcp dport 10251 accept
    tcp dport 10250 accept
    tcp dport 2379 accept
    tcp dport 2380 accept
}

